# Facebook Likes button not displaying when NOT logged into Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

We are using Facebook JavaScript API version 2.0(i.e. sdk.js) to display the Facebook **Likes** button in our website. Previously we had 18+ age restriction for the Facebook Page of our website that we have removed a week before. But still we are not getting the Facebook Likes button when the user is not logged into Facebook. If user is logged into Facebook and accessing our page then the likes button is displaying correctly.

The followings are sample of JavaScript and HTML used in our website to display the Facebook Likes button.

The JavaScript code looks like:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxx&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

The HTML looks like:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>
```

You can find the same from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

Our site contains some adult content. Is Facebook validating the content before displaying the **Likes** button? If so, is there any solution to display the **Likes** button?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Facebook like button is seems OK here.once user logout from the Facebook it will not shows.as well as its checking active user session on the browser.